# How to delete selected item from localStorage which is in array?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Store Item in localstorage and show details in cart view. function for delete any selected Item but it's not working properly.

I'm sending emp_id as key and item_id as value to find item from array.

Here is the array in localstorage.

key is 189

```
[{"item_id":"50","item_name":"Delivery T-Shirt Medium danger","qty":1},{"item_id":"49","item_name":"Delivery T-Shirt Small danger","qty":"1"},{"item_id":"51","item_name":"Delivery T-Shirt Large danger","qty":"1"},{"item_id":"11","item_name":"Bread Pant 30 white","qty":"1"}]
```

Here is Delete Item Function.

```
function Deleteitem(emp_id, item_id) {
  var itemDetails = localStorage.getItem(emp_id);

  if (itemDetails) {
    itemDetails = JSON.parse(itemDetails);

    // Filter out the item to be deleted
    itemDetails = itemDetails.filter(function(item) {
      return item.item_id !== item_id;
    });

    localStorage.setItem(emp_id, JSON.stringify(itemDetails));
  }

  displayItemDetails();
};
```

Sorry for my English.

Comment: how are you calling this function?

Comment: I'm calling this function by onclick `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Deleteitem('+emp_id_input+', '+item_id+');" class="fs-16 btn p-0 cart-trash">`  emp_id is `key`

Comment: which part doesn't work? does `itemDetails = localStorage.getItem(emp_id);` retrieve the right data? is it the filter that doesn't work? do you know that `123 !== "123"`?

Comment: Yes filter part it not working but when I debug this it's giving `item_id`  correct.

Comment: is the argument `item_id` a string or a number? i.e. what is `typeof item_id`

Comment: Thank you I got your point I just update this line in function  `return parseInt(item.item_id) !== parseInt(item_id);` and now it's working fine ...

Comment: so, it seems `item_id` was a Number since all `item.item_id` are String's - the issue is really with the code that calls the function with a Number instead of a String

Comment: @SyedZain Note: you should ideally include [the radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) for `parseInt` as it mentions: "Be careful — this does not always default to 10".

Comment: Maybe a bit of a hack, but if you use `!=` instead of `!==` then the types won't be compared. ID `123` and ID `"123"` will be seen as the same id.

Answer (score 0):

#### You are using strict inequality operator `!==`

`key` is a number and based on the example array you provided `item_id` is a string

Switch to inequality operator or convert all to numbers or strings

```js
itemDetails = itemDetails.filter(function(item) {
      return item.item_id != item_id;
});
```